# Java: Last reference variable are printed out

Tags: java, oop, reference

I have a class that contains list of integer numbers. I wanted to print different sets of integer numbers. But my code prints exactly the same numbers even though the reference variables are different. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OrderedIntListUtility {
    public static void printContains(OrderedIntList list) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.orderedIntegerList.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list.orderedIntegerList[i]);
        }
    }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class OrderedIntList {
    static int[] orderedIntegerList;

    public OrderedIntList(int ... elements) {
        orderedIntegerList = elements;
    }

    public OrderedIntList() {
        orderedIntegerList = null;
    }
}

public class TestOrderedIntList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OrderedIntListUtility operate = new OrderedIntListUtility();
        OrderedIntList listOfA = new OrderedIntList(2,3,1,55,77);
        OrderedIntList listOfB = new OrderedIntList(2,3,5,77);
        operate.printContains(listOfA);
        System.out.println();
        operate.printContains(listOfB);

    }
}
```

the problem is operate.printContains(listOfA) prints the listOfB orderedIntList. I am confused. They are of different variable names right? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what `static` does?

Comment: No, why do you use it here: `static int[] orderedIntegerList;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `OrderedIntList` You have the `static int[] orderedIntegerList;`change it to `int[] orderedIntegerList;`and it will work. Static means available at the *class* level, not at *instance* level

Comment: @TheLostMind i was just editing but you were fast :)

Comment: @code4Life if it answer your question then you can select it as the answer